# How to access Rails WEBrick running on a VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, vps, webrick

I'm fairly new to [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) and VPS. I created a SSH tunnel and managed to install Ruby/Rails, then I created a simple scaffolding app to play around. One question now coming up is, how I can access the running WEBrick server via my browser? I tried the IP of my VPS and added `XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:3000` as the port. But for some reason it does not work. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try port 80 as 3000 can be quite sensitive to firewalls and certain ISP's

Comment: unfortunately it does not work neither, I tried `rails s -p80` and added `:80` to my VPS IP. Still no respond.

Comment: try 'rails s -b *yourip* -p 80'